# Problems with compile grid-column less

Tags: css, grid, less, css-grid

There was a problem with property '**grid-column**'

---

Css:

```
.someClass {
   grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

Less compile it's in css as:

```
.someClass {
   grid-column: 0.25;
}
```

---

But it's works well:

```
.someClass {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

---

How I can use correctly property **grid-column** with **'/'** symbol in Less?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to escape to "slash" when using LESS:

```
.somClass {
    grid-column: 1 e("/") 4;
}
```

But if you have the ability to bypass the "Slash" by decomposing the css property than do it (I personally find it a better way). You can also use the "~" sign to escape expressions, like ~"1/4"

Answer (score 27):

try this

```
.someClass {
  grid-column: ~"1/4";
}
```